# Wait till function finishes in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, blocking

Given I have a recursive method:

```js
tests = {
  add: function (data, option, dataSet) {
    if(option) {
      dataSet.forEach(function (values) {
        this.add(values.data, false);
      }, this);
    }
    console.log(data.name)
  }
}
```

And I would call this by using

```js
tests.add({name: 'test1'}, true, [{data: {name: 'test2'}}]);
```

I assume this would log 'test2' before 'test1' in all cases, but in a lot of cases this does not happen. As far I know the forEach function should be blocking the execution of other lines, but this simply does not happen.

Bit of context: 
The code should add certain components on a webpage. Those components can depend on other components (which are in dataSet). These dependencies should always be recursively added first.

Any ideas?

Comment: `console.log` may be asynchronous, though.

Comment: yeh, have you tried using a callback function with data.name as param and execute console.log there? or is that just for simplicity?

Comment: The console log is just for simplicity. The rest of the function simply adds new components to the webpage. These should be added in the right order (dependencies first.)

Comment: Can you please post some code that reproducably has unexpected output (and what the expected output is)?

Comment: Could you maybe post your actual code that interacts with the DOM?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce whats happens in a jsFiddle, one moment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this inconsistency is that `console.log` is not a synchronous function. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync)

Comment: I've never seen a `console.log` implementation that shows the logged values out of order. This is not what the answers to the question you linked say.

Comment: @Bergi, you can check the last answer in the link i provided, and understand how sometime `console.log` shows you the object the way it looks in the moment of the actual "printing", and not the way it looked when you actually called `console.log`...

@Sebass here said that the result is not consistent, and the asynch nature of `console.log` is IMHO a good direction to explore.

Comment: Well sure that's what can happen to objects, but the example snippet the OP gave a) logs string values b) never modifies any object properties